# How to use class which defined below in Python 3.6?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I need to request class "Product" in class "Collection" below to create a Many-to-Many connection. But the compiler says that the name "Product" is not defined. Are there any possible ways to do it?

```
class Collection(models.Model):
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Product(models.Model):
    collection = models.ManyToManyField(Collection, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I just need to put "Product" in "Collection" and vice versa.

Comment: You can fix the *not defined* error by using a string: `products = models.ManyToManyField('Product', ...)`. However, you don't normally add a many-to-many field to both models. Once you have added `products = models.ManyToManyField('Product', ...)`, each product can have multiple collections and each collection can have multiple products, so you don't have to add `collection = models.ManyToManyField(Collection, ...)` to the `Product` model.

Comment: If I put the product in the collection then I should see, that collection has this product inside. But now it doesn't happen

Comment: This is a django thing, Not a python thing, Using quotes around the class name will lazily create the relation

Comment: The Django admin does not the products for the collection (unless you use [inlines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-models). But the collection will contain the product. You can check in the Django shell with `collection.product_set.all()`

Comment: Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve]. Is the issue specific/particular to Python 3.6?

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring class `Product` followed by `Collection`, then simply use it like :

```
class Collection(models.Model):
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and  for Product you can think of using just use string attr. like `'Collection'`